# Modify Azure FunctionKey or expire after a certain time

Tags: azure, azure-functions

1. I'm new to azure functions. So I have build a normal http trigger which takes 2 parameters as input. So using those parameters I'm pulling data from gen2 locations and showing it at the response side.
2. Currently I'm using function keys (created one for my testing purpose) and using the same.
3. So the Request which I'm passing looks something like this:-

**https://(APP-NAME).azurewebsites.net/(RESOURCE-PATH)?param1=&param2=,code=(Generated by function key)**

Till this point everything is working well. Now I'm sharing this request API to set of people.

4. The response API is data which they can see. Now I'm trying to make the code dynamic (like the existing one should expire after a certain time and I should be able to pick new function key from the same function key name I created)
5. Is is possible to generate our own function keys (using some random key generator) from the back end and keep updating the values after a particular time interval

---

Please feel free to provide more suggestions.

Comment: You know that if the key is changed, the calling application will need to know about it.  Have you factored in that thinking?  I don't see that mentioned anywhere in your question.

Answer (score 0):

- Azure has provided an api for the function key management in azure
  function. This api will allow you to create, delete and update the
  function keys. It is available at runtime when your app is deployed
  in the azure.
- According to this   [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Key-management-API) you can make the required changes to the function keys,   also you need to pass Bearer Token credentials with you get/post   requests as you must be authorized to be able to view or make changes   to the function keys.
- Since you want to change the function key after a particular interval   of time, you can use a time trigger which will change the function   key (after a particular interval of time) using the above api.
- To generate a key use any random string generator provided in the
  programming language of your choice  . You can then store the new
  generated  function key in a blob storage for further use.

**REFERENCES:**
[Timer trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?msclkid=dad58f46afe011ec99c3fa9deb173dc6&tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-javascript)

Comment: Thanks I'm able to run add/update the function key but now I'm facing different issue. I tried to incorporate the API in my python code and getting 403 error. Below is what I did.1) Generated the url: URL:
'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xyz1/resourceGroups/xyz2/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/func_appname/functions/func_name/keys/poc_testing1?api-version=2021-02-01{"Properties":{"Name": "poc_testing1","Value": "asdsda"}}'. 2) Generated the bearer token using the service principal I'm using to authenticate my storage acc, stored it in auth_token=token["accessToken"].